# IBMi bash upgrade

Tags: bash, rvm, ibm-midrange

I am trying to install rvm in [PASE](https://www-304.ibm.com/partnerworld/wps/servlet/ContentHandler/pw_com_porting_ibmi_pase) on [IBMi](http://www-03.ibm.com/systems/i/) (v7.1) but it is failing because it states bash version 3.2.25 is required.  Running `bash --version` via `CALL QP2TERM` states I am running the following version:

```
GNU bash, version 3.00.16(1)-release (powerpc-ibm-aix5.1) 
Copyright (C) 2004 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
```

Anybody know if it is possible to upgrade the bash version on IBMi (aka iSeries)?

Answer (score 0):

To upgrade bash on IBM i do the following:

```
CALL QP2TERM

cd /QOpenSys/download
wget http://www.oss4aix.org/download/RPMS/bash/bash-doc-3.2-4.aix5.1.ppc.rpm              
wget http://www.oss4aix.org/download/RPMS/bash/bash-4.1-4.aix5.1.ppc.rpm
rpm --ignoreos --ignorearch --nodeps --replacepkgs -hUv bash-doc-3.2-4.aix5.1.ppc.rpm      
rpm --ignoreos --ignorearch --nodeps --replacepkgs -hUv bash-4.1-4.aix5.1.ppc.rpm
```

If you don't have wget or rpm installed then first go to the [YoungiProfessionals.com](http://www.youngiprofessionals.com/wiki/PASE/OpenSourceBinaries) site and follow the instructions there.